# Why was my post deemed off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

[Hypernym for "to increase" and "to decrease"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245463/hypernym-for-to-increase-and-to-decrease)

It is on topic, I'm guessing someone saw I was asking about a video game and instantly closed it. It's about English if you actually read it. I see nothing wrong with it. Could someone explain why this was closed so I can not make the same mistake in the future?

Comment: 1) the comments suggesting 'change' and a thesaurus lookup were not enough? 2) if the 'game' hypothesis is right, go ahead and excise the game references in future (it'll make it seem more answerable). Or if context makes things easier, move the motivation to the end.

Comment: RegDwight will have to weigh in, since he cast a single binding closevote on it.  The question looks okay to me, except that it doesn't show any research effort.  Perhaps you should have slept on it, as mentioned in the question, before asking.  :-)

Comment: I think Reg's final comment *(Change, adjust, customize, alter, specify, adapt, modify)* is quite enough to show that the question is essentially General Reference. To make it On Topic, OP would need to explain why none of those obvious candidates are suitable for his intended context.

Comment: Ah. Thanks! I'll have to be more in-detail next time I post. Explain the obvious and why they don't work.

Comment: Your attitude is refreshingly upbeat, Jared Kauffman. It certainly is hard sometimes to think of a word that means two opposing things (like "to increase or to decrease"), simply because you may be too close to the individual trees to see the forest. I'm fairly sure that it was the simplicity of the valid answers ("change," "alter," "adjust," etc.), and not the connection to gaming, that prompted the closure. Anyway, I hope you come back to this site with any questions you may have about English language and usage in future.